# ParseError after a previously successful compile

Tags: error, import

I received a successful compile message:

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling .\contracts\coffeeAccessControl\ConsumerRole.sol
> Compiling .\contracts\coffeeAccessControl\Roles.sol
> Compilation warnings encountered:

    Warning: SPDX license identifier not provided in source file. Before publishing, consider adding a comment containing "SPDX-License-Identifier: <SPDX-License>" to each source file. Use "SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED" for non-
open-source code. Please see https://spdx.org for more information.
--> /C/Users/alexa/WebstormProjects/project-koffie/contracts/coffeeAccessControl/ConsumerRole.sol

> Artifacts written to C:\Users\alexa\WebstormProjects\project-koffie\build\contracts
> Compiled successfully using:
   - solc: 0.8.6+commit.11564f7e.Emscripten.clang
```

And then added the license tag `// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED` as per warning message

Then tried compiling once again just to ensure the warning would clear, and now I'm receiving a `ParseError` for `Roles.sol`:

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Compiling .\contracts\coffeeAccessControl\ConsumerRole.sol

ParserError: Source "/C/Users/alexa/WebstormProjects/project-koffie/contracts/coffeeAccessControl/Roles.sol" not found
 --> /C/Users/alexa/WebstormProjects/project-koffie/contracts/coffeeAccessControl/ConsumerRole.sol:5:1:
  |
5 | import "./Roles.sol";
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Compilation failed. See above.
Truffle v5.4.1 (core: 5.4.1)
Node v14.17.0
```

I also tried removing the license comment but the `ParseError` still throws. Any ideas? Again, nothing else was changed outside of adding the license comment

Comment: And now it compiles again...I'm new to solidity, is this a common bug within the language or maybe Truffle more broadly?

Answer (score 0):

It's failing on the `import` line 5th in your contract file `ConsumerRole.sol`

In general could not find a file `Roles.sol`

```
  |
5 | import "./Roles.sol";
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```